# Stopping mod_rewrite rule match, circular execution

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have old.htm and new.htm on a directory, and I need to load file.php every time someone access old.htm, and load old.htm every time some access new.htm.

Here are my non-working rules:

```
RewriteRule ^old\.htm$ file.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule ^new\.htm$ old.htm [L]
```

When old.htm is accessed, file.php is called. When new.htm is accessed, old.htm is "accessed" again, rewriting it to file.php. So, in the end, accessing new.php loads file.php, but I want to stop at old.htm.

Any ideas?

Here's RewriteLogLevel 3 output if it helps:

old.htm

```
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/old.htm -> old.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^old\.htm$' to uri 'old.htm'
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (2) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] rewrite old.htm -> file.php?/arquivoweb/old.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) split uri=file.php?/arquivoweb/old.htm -> uri=file.php, args=/arquivoweb/old.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] add per-dir prefix: file.php -> D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (2) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip document_root prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php -> /arquivoweb/file.php
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (1) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] internal redirect with /arquivoweb/file.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#200fb20/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php -> file.php
[rid#200fb20/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^old\.htm$' to uri 'file.php'
[rid#200fb20/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php -> file.php
[rid#200fb20/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^new\.htm$' to uri 'file.php'
[rid#200fb20/initial/redir#1] (1) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] pass through D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php
```

new.htm

```
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/new.htm -> new.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^old\.htm$' to uri 'new.htm'
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/new.htm -> new.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^new\.htm$' to uri 'new.htm'
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (2) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] rewrite new.htm -> old.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] add per-dir prefix: old.htm -> D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/old.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (2) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip document_root prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/old.htm -> /arquivoweb/old.htm
[rid#2006ee0/initial] (1) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] internal redirect with /arquivoweb/old.htm [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/old.htm -> old.htm
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^old\.htm$' to uri 'old.htm'
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (2) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] rewrite old.htm -> file.php?/arquivoweb/old.htm
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (3) split uri=file.php?/arquivoweb/old.htm -> uri=file.php, args=/arquivoweb/old.htm
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] add per-dir prefix: file.php -> D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (2) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip document_root prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php -> /arquivoweb/file.php
[rid#200fa90/initial/redir#1] (1) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] internal redirect with /arquivoweb/file.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#20e6c70/initial/redir#2] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php -> file.php
[rid#20e6c70/initial/redir#2] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^old\.htm$' to uri 'file.php'
[rid#20e6c70/initial/redir#2] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php -> file.php
[rid#20e6c70/initial/redir#2] (3) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] applying pattern '^new\.htm$' to uri 'file.php'
[rid#20e6c70/initial/redir#2] (1) [per-dir D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/] pass through D:/dev/www/estadao/arquivoweb/file.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to additionally check the original requested URL instead of just the current URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /old\.html
RewriteRule ^old\.htm$ file.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule ^new\.htm$ old.htm [L]
```

Comment: After a little hacking on the regex I got it working, thanks :) There's nothing wrong with your answer, by the way! I just had to get all the characters right on `^GET\ /arquivoweb/[a-z]+/[\d]{4}/[a-z]+/not[\d]{8}p[\d]+\.htm`, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's gonna happen with `new.htm` since the log seems only to cover the case of `old.htm`.  But, try adding the `NS` flag to the `old.htm` rewrite rule to prevent it firing on the subrequest after the PHP script has been introduced.

Comment: Hi jbourque, I separated the log to show what's from old.htm and what's from new.htm. I've tried adding `NS` in both lines and couldn't make it work :( I'm think the error happens on `internal redirect with /arquivoweb/old.htm [INTERNAL REDIRECT]` which should be an internal rewrite, maybe? Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm stumped as far as the rewrite rules are concerned.  Can you address it with a redirect, rather than a rewrite?  Or can you fix it at the file system level, make a symbolic link from new.htm to old.htm rather than rewriting the URI?

Comment: Hi jbourque, the actual rewrite rules that I'm using are a little more complicated than the reduced example on my original question, which is something that I tested, doesn't work, but it's the simplest form which emulates what I'm trying to do. There are dozens of thousands of files, with hundreds of thousands of visitors a day :) I'm trying to avoid redirects or opening the file with php, and just sticking with the rewrite.